# Svelte custom store connecting to a database REDIS

Tags: javascript, redis, svelte, datastore, ioredis

I cannot connect to a Redis database inside a Svelte App. For this I'm trying to make a custom store.js, but I have been already struggling so much to import the node client (no matter the client I use). For the 'ioredis', the documentation says to use it like:

```
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const redis = new Redis();
```

Can anybody throw some hints on how to implement it? The idea would be to have an App, which only purpose is to parse/retrieve values to/from a REDIS db with pub/sub methods.
I guess im missing something with rollup and the way it handles nodejs dependencies when compiling, or maybe it is not possible at all go that way?

Answer (score 0):

Stores need to be able to run in the browser, so they won't be able to communicate with `redis` directly or import node packages (unless the imported package is isomorphic or has a browser equivalent).

Instead of direct access, you can create an HTTP server that wraps the Redis calls.

The store is a copy of the remote data. Every time the client updates Redis (via HTTP endpoint), it should update the local store too.

Something like:

```js
export const store = writable(...)

export async function updateRedis(stuff) {
  const response = await fetch('/my-update-url', {method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(stuff)})
  const result = await result.json()

  // tell the store about new results, either with set() or update()
  store.set(result)
}
```

Comment: Aha, thanks! If I understand, I do need the chain browser->http-server->REDIS....

Comment: exactly! you'll need an http server between the browser and redis (except if you are doing all rendering server side)

Comment: Umm, still a bit confused on how all the components work together. I have a Svelte App that does not need to communicate at all with the world (just running in my localhost, just a graphical user interface to my localhost REDIS database). This Svelte App, I launch in a terminal, where a node program (Rollup or Webpack or Sirv-cli?) is in charge of compiling and sending a bundle.js direct to the browser. Wouldnt be possible to run my node client (ioredis) within that server (sirv-cli is the default?) and not needing any fetch, or html layer in between my database and my App?

Comment: Is this possible as you said, by "doing all rendering server side"? In that case, any hint to do it?

Comment: You can do rendering server-side, by calling `svelte.compile(source, {generate: "ssr"})`. That will give you the HTML of your svelte components as a string.